# Deckset app alternative

Tags: alternative, slideshow, markdown

Mac OSX have a good app called deckset http://decksetapp.com/.

This app make slides from markdown text....

Someone know an alternative for ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check [remark.js](http://www.remarkjs.com).
It's not as easy to use as DeckSet but it does the job pretty well.

Comment: Like you said it is not easy as deckset but really the best alternative that i've seen and I can be use it. Maybe in future someone makes an app that facilities the use of remark.